# Human-readable function names in chrome profiler for Emscripten-generated code

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, firefox, emscripten

I use Emscripten to compile some C++ code into Javascript. When I try to profile it in Firefox, I get nice human-readable names for classes, methods and templates, like this:

[image]

But when doing the same in Chrome, I get symbol names as linker expects them to look like:

[image]

Is it possible to make Chrome's profiler to print more readable names like in firefox?

I tried `-g4`, `--profiling` and `-O0` options of `emcc` compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The nice formatting is the "demangled" name. That's probably a browser-provided QoL feature, which is up to the browser implementors if they want to implement. The Chrome debugging experience for emscripten code seems to have gotten [plenty of work done to improve it](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020/) since this question was written. I wouldn't be surprised if names are demangled now.

As an aside, for *stack traces*, [Emscripten provides a compiler/linker flag](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/Debugging.html#compiler-settings) to do demangling in them:

> `DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1` links in code to automatically demangle stack traces, that is, emit human-readable C++ function names instead of `_ZN..` ones.

There's also [some relevant discussion in the Emscripten issue tracker on this topic](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/14205).

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results profiling with demangled function names in Chrome (Chromium on Linux) with the following flags:

Compiler:

```
-O0
-g3
```

Linker:

```
-O0
-g3
--profiling-funcs
-sDEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1
```

This combination produces profiling traces showing full, demangled C++ function names in the browser profiler for me at the time of writing.